# In Gecko 2.0 (Firefox 4) how do you interact with (send windows messages to) a tab that is not currently focused?

Tags: c++, firefox, ui-automation, gecko

Say your automating Firefox, and you want to do crazy things like, emulating a raw keystroke typing 'return' but to a tab window that is not currently in focus/active/ontop.

Using ideas in 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Finding_Window_Handles
you can get a hwnd, and then do something like

```
::PostMessage(hWND, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RETURN, 0);
::PostMessage(hWND,WM_CHAR,VK_RETURN,0);
::PostMessage(hWND, WM_KEYUP, VK_RETURN, 0);
```

However according to that same link in Gecko 2.0 (Firefox 4 & others) there will no longer be a windows native hwnd representing each tab.

Having various automation actions I wish to take, I'm trying to work out if there is some replacement way to send windows messages to a tab that is not currently focused?

or will require a larger re write to replace these actions with some other more 'gecko native' process?

Comment: selenium no? http://seleniumhq.org/

Comment: I can't use selenium directly, but maybe I can find what I need in the source code...

Comment: According to http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cpp/webdriver-firefox/nsIAccessibleDocumentWrapper.h  selenium doesn't appear to support Gecko 2.0 yet.  It has been helpful for earlier versions though.

Comment: maybe you can do a nice contribution to their project ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to interact with Firefox out-of-process then the only way I know of that's supported are the accessibility APIs.

If you're writing an extension then you can simply create a keypress event with the relevant key or character code and dispatch it to the appropriate element.